# Remove multiple values of data in filter using macro

Tags: vba, excel, filter

Suppose I have a set of data and i want to filter the column date. I have another macro that can generate the values of date (value to be filtered). the value is multiple values of date and can be different value every time (but in same format). the expected result will be the the filtered source table.

so I want to apply those value in my date column using macro. is there an efficient way to do?

source data and expected result as below
[image: source data and expected result]

Comment: You want an efficient way.  What is your way now?

Comment: Apply filter (tons of answers on how to filter by date wheather it be constant or dynamic) and then copy/paste visible cells (tons of answers on how to do this as well). **Did you do any research before asking for help?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way is **filter**.  But the format of your `value to be filtered` have to be changed.

I use `AdvancedFilter` method.

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1:C8").AdvancedFilter _
        Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Range("F1:G2"), _
        CopyToRange:=Range("I1:K1"), Unique:=False
End Sub
```

then

[image]